# expanding/collapsing nested nodes in xslt

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have an xml in the following format;

```
<BasePeriod>
.
.
.
.
<Period>
    <start> stdate1 </start>
    <end> endate1 </end>
    <subperiod>
       <substart> substart1 </substart>
       <subend> subend1 </subend>
    </subperiod>
    <type> abc1 </type>
</Period>
<Period>
    <start> stdate1 </start>
    <end> endate1 </end>
    <subperiod>
       <substart> substart2 </substart>
       <subend> subend2 </subend>
    </subperiod>
    <type> abc2 </type>
</Period>
<Period>
    <start> stdate1 </start>
    <end> endate1 </end>
    <subperiod>
       <substart> substart3 </substart>
       <subend> subend3 </subend>
    </subperiod>
    <type> abc3 </type>
</Period>
</BasePeriod>
```

What I would like to do is - have the Period and SubPeriod collapsed when I open the html and then expand them when I click on it.

I have the following xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="SvcPeriods/BasePeriod">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="startDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="endDate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:expandIt(per_expand{position()}), period_expand{position()}" name="period_expand{position()}" class="expandit">Periods</a>
        <div id="per_expand{position()}" style="display:none;" >
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Start Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        End Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Sub Periods
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Type
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <xsl:for-each select="Period">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="start"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="end"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:expandIt(subper_expand{position()}), subperiod_expand{position()}" name="subperiod_expand{position()}" class="expandit">Sub Periods</a>
                            <div id="subper_expand{position()}" style="display:none;" >
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th >
                                            Start Date
                                        </th>
                                        <th >
                                            End Date
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="subperiod">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="substart"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="subend"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<script language="JavaScript">
function expandIt(whichEl, link) {
    whichEl.style.display = (whichEl.style.display == "none" ) ? "" : "none";
    if ( link ) { 
         if ( link.innerHTML ) {
            if ( whichEl.style.display == "none" ) {
                  link.innerHTML = "[+] " + link.innerHTML.substring( 4 );
               } else {
                  link.innerHTML = "[-] " + link.innerHTML.substring( 4 );
               }
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
```

With the above, I'm not able to expand the sub period. I then tried passing `document.getElementById(subper_expand{position()}')` as the first argument to the `expandit` function. This time I'm able to expand the sub period, but the issue is, that it always refers to the sub period of the first period (even when I'm clicking inside the 2nd or 3rd period).

Can someone help me out here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Break your XSL into multiple templates

It's good practice to use many templates rather then one with "hidden" `<xsl:for-each>` elements.

**BasePeriod:**

```
<xsl:template match="SvcPeriods/BasePeriod">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="startDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="endDate"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:expandIt(per_expand{position()},
                per_expand{position()})"
                name="period_expand{position()}" class="expandit">Periods</a>
            <div id="per_expand{position()}" style="display:none;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Start Date </th>
                        <th> End Date </th>
                        <th> Sub Periods </th>
                        <th> Type </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Period"/>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <xsl:call-template name="expandIt"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Period:**

```
<xsl:template match="Period">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="start"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="end"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:expandIt(subper_expand{position()},
                subperiod_expand{position()})"
                name="subperiod_expand{position()}" 
                class="expandit">Sub Periods</a> 
            <div id="subper_expand{position()}" style="display:none;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Start Date </th>
                        <th> End Date </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="subperiod"/>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

**subperiod:**

```
<xsl:template match="subperiod">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="substart"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="subend"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

**expandIt:**

```
<xsl:template name="expandIt">
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function expandIt(whichEl, link) {
        whichEl.style.display = (whichEl.style.display == "none" ) ? "" : "none";
        if ( link ) { 
             if ( link.innerHTML ) {
                if ( whichEl.style.display == "none" ) {
                      link.innerHTML = "[+] " + link.innerHTML.substring( 4 );
                   } else {
                      link.innerHTML = "[-] " + link.innerHTML.substring( 4 );
                   }
             }
         }
     }
    </script>       
</xsl:template>
```

---

As you see I changed:

```
<a href="javascript:expandIt(subper_expand{position()}),
    subperiod_expand{position()}"
```

to:

```
<a href="javascript:expandIt(subper_expand{position()},
    subperiod_expand{position()})"
```

(same for per_expand). Result (using Opera):

[image]

Next (clicking Periods link):

[image]

Next (clicking sub periods):

[image]

It seems to be ok, expanding and collapsing work as expected.

Comment: I have had a look at your suggested answer and while it doesn't work for firefox, the overall idea worked. The part that didn't work for firefox was the direct referencing of ids (you need to use getElementById for that). Also, innerHTML is not what should be modified, but rather textContent (innerText in IE/Opera world). A reference like "whichEl.style.display" would become "document.getElementById(whichEl).style.display". Also you should not use "name" (unless in forms) but rather use "id". In 1. template, 2. argument to expandIt should be "period_expand{position()}". Remember to add "[+] ".