# expanding/collapsing nested nodes in xslt (Part 2)

Tags: xslt

This is continuation to my earlier post [expanding/collapsing nested nodes in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417148/expanding-collapsing-nested-nodes-in-xslt)

For some reason I'm not able to add comment to my previous post.

I tried the solution provided and it works when there is only one base period. If there are multiple base periods, it doesnt work.

Note that I'm using IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's rather easy to handle multiple base periods. Simple approach is to add second identifier for `subper_expand` div container (and its anchor) to distinguish them in individual base periods, that is:

```
subper_expand{base period position}_{periond position}
```

**BasePeriod:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Period">
    <xsl:with-param name="bpPos" select="position()"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**Period:**

```
<xsl:param name="bpPos"/>

<xsl:variable name="subper">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('subper_expand', $bpPos, '_', position())"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="subperiod">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('subperiod_expand', $bpPos, '_', position())"/>
</xsl:variable>
...
<a href="javascript:expandIt({$subper}, {$subperiod})"
   name="{$subperiod}" class="expandit">Sub Periods</a>
<div id="{$subper}" style="display:none;">
```

As you see it looks more readable using xsl's variables.

Comment: Thank you. Using the position as a param worked and the issue is now resolved.