# xsl expand and collapse after "N" child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I have XML that can has variable number of child elements.
We need a way to add a expand / collapse feature when there are more than "N" number of child elements.
Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestXML>
    <N>Test</N>
    <NTList>
        <NT>
            <NT1>NT1 Test 1</NT1>
            <NT2>NT2 Test 1</NT2>
        </NT>
        <NT>
            <NT1>NT1 Test 2</NT1>
            <NT2>NT2 Test 2</NT2>
        </NT>
        <NT>
            <NT1>NT1 Test 3</NT1>
            <NT2>NT2 Test 3</NT2>
        </NT>
    </NTList>
</TestXML>
```

So in this example we would like to add the expand / collapse if there are more than 2 "NT" inside the "NTList".

I think [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417148/expanding-collapsing-nested-nodes-in-xslt) is close but I can't find a way to determine when to add the expand / collapse after "N" records has been reached.

Something very basic like this for the HTML output:

```
N : Test
NTLIST
    NT (1)
        NT1 : NT1 Test 1
        NT2 : NT2 Test 1
    NT (2)
        NT1 : NT1 Test 2
        NT2 : NT2 Test 2
    NT (+More) <- where this is the link to click to expand the 3rd NT.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have jQuery as tag I think following solution could work for you. You can determine the Nth record using `position()` in an `xsl:for-each` loop. As example for N = 3:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
     omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="TestXML">
    <ul>
      <li>N : Test<br/>NTLIST
        <xsl:for-each select="NTList/NT">       
          <ul>
            <li>
              <xsl:if test="position() >=3">
                <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'toggle'"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of select="
               if(position() &lt; 3)
               then concat(local-name(),  ' (', position(),')')
               else concat(local-name(),  ' (+More)')"/>
                <ul>
                  <xsl:if test="position() >=3">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'hidden'"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <li>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </li>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

When applied to your input XML produces the ouput (relevant part):

```
<ul>
   <li>N : Test<br/>NTLIST
      <ul>
         <li>NT (1)
            <ul>
               <li>NT1 Test 1</li>
               <li>NT2 Test 1</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>NT (2)
            <ul>
               <li>NT1 Test 2</li>
               <li>NT2 Test 2</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li class="toggle">NT (+More)
            <ul class="hidden">
               <li>NT1 Test 3</li>
               <li>NT2 Test 3</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Following CSS hides the lists that have class `hidden` and removes the bulletpoints from the list elements:

```
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.hidden
{
  display:none;)
}
```

And following jQuery:

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function () {
  $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

will toggle the hidden lists.  Just added a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8ywka34/) for the result.

For reference: [position()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

**Update:** As mentioned in the comment, suggested approach does not work for OP settings (Visual Studio) because of using `if` in a `select` attribute and using `select` in an `xsl:attribute`. Following XSLT generates the same output using `xsl:when` statements instead. I can't test if it will work in Visual Studio but if not, you can just add a comment with the new error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat"
omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="TestXML">
    <ul>
        <li>
            N : Test<br/>
            NTLIST
            <xsl:for-each select="NTList/NT">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <xsl:if test="position() >=3">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">toggle</xsl:attribute>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() &lt; 3">
                          <xsl:value-of 
                               select="concat(local-name(), ' (', position(),')')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:value-of 
                                 select="concat(local-name(), ' (+More)')"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                      <ul>
                        <xsl:if test="position() >=3">
                          <xsl:attribute name="class">hidden</xsl:attribute>     
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                          <li>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                          </li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Update:** As mentioned in the comment, I overlooked to change two `select`-statements in `xsl:attribute`. Fixed it by adjusting to e.g. `<xsl:attribute name="class">hidden</xsl:attribute>`. To avoid potential issues in case of whitespace or linebreaks this could be changed by adding  `<xsl:text>` as wrapper:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">
  <xsl:text>hidden</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: The code you posted does not work in my IDE "VS". For example, the if(position) inside the select give me error "if() is an unknown XSLT function." also the select on the xsl:attribute gives me error "select is an invalid attribute for the xsl:attribute element". I am researching into the "xsl:choose" to replace the "if(position)" but if you know some way to make this code work in Visual Studio or  IE, I would much appreciate it. Thank You for your help.

Comment: @goroth Glad to be of help. I've just updated my answer with an adjusted XSLT. I can't test it in VS but you can give it a try and in case of new errors add a comment.

Comment: your original code with the xsl:if worked but the select=if did not so you didn't have to change all the if's to choose statements. The only piece the still did not work is the xsl:attribute select. So I changed it to <xsl:attribute name="class">toggle</xsl:attribute>. I will post my full code in a edit above one I have it looking / working better with jquery.

Comment: @goroth Thanks for the info, just overlooked that and corrected my answer.